# Error con modelos en Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Recién estoy aprendiendo Django(perdón si hago tontadas),y Tengo un error cuando intento heredar 'forms.ModelForms' en un modelo, obtengo el siguiente error....

**Error:**

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Este seria mi modelo(models.py), no se si mi clase abstracta es el problema(si esta mal la forma en la que la programe):

**Codigo:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django import forms

# Create your models here.

class CommonsData(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)

    class Meta():
        abstract = True

class RegisteredUsers(CommonsData, forms.ModelForm):
    user = models.CharField(max_length = 25, unique = True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 25, widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    register_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'registered_users'
        ordering = ['-register_date']
```

Bueno, trato de conseguir un 'password input' algo así al heredar 'forms.ModelForm', no se si esta es la manera correcta o hay otra...

**Bueno de antemano gracias por sus respuestas!**

Comment: Veo que tu problema es que tu modelo estás intentando que herede de `forms.ModelForm` lo cual es algo completamente distinto a `models.Model`, `models.Model` hace referencia solo a tu esquema de base de datos y es la ORM que te ofrece Django para tu trabajar, mientras que `forms.ModelForm` es una clase para crear formularios basados en un modelo, aunque pueden estar relacionados, su uso es distinto y no es conveniente que una clase pueda heredar de ambas clases a la vez. Te recomiendo leer un poco más acerca de los forms de Django para que te des una idea de como funcionan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te dijo ya una respuesta, estas mezclando el uso de los formularios con la definición de los modelos.

Tu código debería ser algo como:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django import forms

# Create your models here.

class CommonsData(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)

    class Meta():
        abstract = True

class RegisteredUsers(CommonsData):#Heredas CommonsData que a su vez ya heredo models.Model
    user = models.CharField(max_length = 25, unique = True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 25)
    register_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'registered_users'
        ordering = ['-register_date']
```

y deberías tener un archivo **forms.py** dentro de tu aplicación que sea algo así:

```
from django import forms #Importamos forms
from .models import RegisteredUsers #Importas tu modelo

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    #Con esto, el form de la contraseña va a adquirir todas las propiedades
    #que se necesita para insertar contraseña
    class Meta:
         model = RegisteredUser
         fields = ['user', 'password', 'email']
         #Le estamos diciendo al formulario que atributos del modelo que creaste vas a insertar
         #por eso no incluyo register_date
```

Lo único que falta es utilizar este form en una vista, en tu archivo views.py:

```
from turnos.forms import SignUpForm #Importamos los forms que ya creamos
from django.views.generic import View

class SignUpView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            nuevo_usuario = form.save()
            nuevo_usuario.save()
        return render(request, 'SignUp.html', {'form': form})

    def get(self, request):
        form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'SignUp.html', {'form': form})
```

En fin, ahí tenes un ejemplo de una estructura básica para que crees un form en base a un modelo y una vista que lo utilice.
Lo único que te queda por hacer es hacer un template ( en mi ejemplo SignUp.html ) y insertar los campos del formulario

**No probé realmente este código, simplemente escribí una estructura representativa, pero te puede servir como guía**

Comment: No entendí como funciona el 'model = RegisteredUser' o para que es, me puedes explicar por favor?

Comment: @JulioCesar creo que eso ya hace parte de otra pregunta, pero básicamente Django hace uso en casi todo su core de algo conocido como `metaprogramación`, pero no es más que una forma de decirle a Django que para la clase `SignUpForm` cuando se llame el método `.save()` va a crear una instancia y un registro del modelo `RegisteredUser`, esa es la cualidad especial y la diferencia entre `forms.ModelForm` y `forms.Form` que uno tiene el método `.save()` y el otro no, pero para saber a donde terminarán los datos, requiere de metadatos, y esos metadatos los tiene tu clase de `RegisteredUser`

Comment: OK muchas gracias!